# How to call a function in a "For Each cell In Range" loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want code that checks a cell to see if the sheet is in mode A or mode B, then check if the accessory is compatible with this mode. I have written this so far and it works except for when it calls the function.

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A8")
If cell.Value = "Acessorie X" The 
  If Range("B1").Value = "Mode A" The MsgBox ("Warning: Acessorie X not compatible"), , "Invalid Entry"
  Call function1(cell.Range)
End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: If `function1` expects a `Range` as a parameter, then just use pass it `cell`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you created function1? Does it error on the line `Call function1(cell.Range)` or when entering function1?
e.g.
`Function function1(rng1 As Range)
 For Each cell In Range(rng1)
 Next Cell
End Function`

Comment: You have two `iI` statements. Could you share exactly what should happen if `cell.Value = "Acessorire X"` and what if not? And what should happen if `Range("B1").Value = "Mode A"` and what if not? That's 4 to 6 cases. Sharing the code of `function1` would also be useful.